# resttemplate GET wrapps a set in an additional tag

Tags: spring, kotlin, resttemplate

Calling the endpoint from a browser returns back my set

```
[ {"prop1" : "A"}, {"prop1" : "B"} ]
```

The weird thing happens when I call this via resttemplate, it comes back as `{"endpointPath": [ {"prop1" : "A"}, {"prop1" : "B"} ] }`
The endpoint path is endpoint-path, but somehow in the json is camel-cased.
The call is like this:

```
config.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, typeRef).body
```

where typeRef is `= object : ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<MyPojo>>() {}`

I don't know why this happens. Do you?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I don't really see how that answers my question, can you please explain?
What I say here is that the resttemplate call modifies the structure of the json received, I expect a set, and I get a a set within a json object.

Comment: Alright, I guess I misread the question a bit, reopened it